# Could cypress wait for some element appears?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, visual-testing

I want made cypress to wait until full of my web app will be open.
Some elements load independently of each other, and I have to wait for full screen to be loaded, because after this I want to take snapshot with percy.
How can I handle with it? Is it possible to make it dependent on some e.g html classes?

Comment: You can find a visual indicator in the UI and wait for it. For example, a page is fully loaded when the loading indicator is gone, you can do: `cy.get('.loading-spinner').should('not.be.visible')` Cypress will wait until the assertion is passed or timeout. You can increase the default timeout if the page takes longer than Cypress' default

Answer (score 1):

The cypress hack for this problem would be `cy.get('button', {timeout: 2000})`

However, I would suggest using a library like [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until). This would provide you with a syntax like

```
  cy.waitUntil(() =>
    cy.get("input[type=hidden]#recaptchatoken")
      .then($el => $el.val()))
      // ... then, check that it's valid string asserting about it
      .then(token => expect(token).to.be.a("string").to.have.length.within(1,1000));
```